# How to check if a nested list of strings contain the same elements

Tags: r, list

I have nested lists of strings:

```
mylist1 <- list(
   list(c("banana"),c("banana","tomato"))
 , list(c("", "nut"), c("nut", "orange"))
   )

mylist2 <- list(
   list(c("orange","nut"), c("nut", ""))
 , list(c("tomato","banana"),c("banana"))
)

mylist3 <- list(
   list(c("orange","nut"), c("nut"))
 , list(c("tomato","banana"),c("banana"))
)
```

Note: In the above example `mylist1`and `mylist2` would be equal. But `mylist3` is different from `mylist1` and `mylist2`, as the sublist with the empty string and "nut" is missing `c("nut", "")`

The order of the elements in the lists are not important. I want a function that compares two such lists and returns a boolean, if they are equal when disregarding the order of elements.

Essentially my nested lists of type string represent mathematical sets. I want to compare two such nested lists, but as they represent sets the order is not important. I want to get a boolean (true/false) value back.

Comment: can't you just unlist all the elements? `all(unlist(mylist1) %in% unlist(mylist2)); 
all(unlist(mylist1) %in% unlist(mylist3))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont have duplicated items in your lists, you can use Set and [Set Operations](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sets.html).
So it would be something like:

```
(set1 <-c(mylist1, NA))
(set2 <-c(mylist2, NA))
setequal(set1, set2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always compare each element of list 1 to second list's elements, but that would take a long time and can be impossible (On^2) (it is going to be a nested loop)
 The other option that comes to my mind is to sort both lists and then do a comparison between them, since they are both sorted you only have to check an element in list 1 to the same order element in list 2. 
 The second option is theoretically going to be faster: (assuming sorting the lists take nLog(n))
 it is going to be 2*nLog(n) + n (number of times you check the elements of both sorted lists) which is OnLog(n)